# jQuery stopPropagation - function fire up again

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, bind, event-propagation

can you tell me how to stop function propagation. I need to fire up some function again after first click action. I using scrollTo jquery plugin for scroll my content and when i click in my 'fire' button content scroll nicely, but i can't do this again... Thx 4 help.

This is my function:

```
$('.arrow_down').bind('click', function(event){
    $('.recipe_single_view_right_panel').scrollTo({top:'280px', left:'0'}, 800 );
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: looks like you're scrolling to a fixed value... so clicking twice will do nothing, unless you manually scroll elsewhere.

Comment: when i set +=280px it's scroll me down/bottom automaticly

Comment: what do you mean with that? `+=280px` should just scroll another 280px down

Comment: should but it does't work :( http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Comment: well, it is working on this demo-page. (the link "Relative Position(hash)" for example). Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: i use this structure but it scrolling down and down, also my console is clean

Comment: it _should_ scroll down and down, right? or is it scrolling right to the bottom after the first click?

Comment: yeah, when i click one time it scrolling to bottom, not for 280px

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15098/discussion-between-lukasz-borawski-and-gni33)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not need to use a big, feature-rich plugin to achieve that.

All you need to do is to alter the `scrollTop` - property of the wrapping element. I created a fiddle with a simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/k9bdY/

The wrapping element is set to `overflow: scroll`, animating the scrolling-position on click is fairly simple then when using jQuery:

```
$('.scroll-btn').on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#wrapper').animate({
        scrollTop: "+=200px"            
    }, 800);
});​
```